# Why PhpStorm hotkeys (Ctr+Alt+Left, Shift+F6) not works with xfce4 desktop environment?

Tags: xfce

I use PhpStorm. I use x2go and xpra for connect to remote machine with launched phpstorm.

If on terminal-system installed any desktop environment, exclude xfce4 - PhpStorm hotkeys work perfectly.

If installed xfce4 on terminal-system - some hotkeys in PhpStorm not work (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>)

On xfce4 window-manager and keyboard-manager turn off all keyboard shortcuts similar to PhpStorm hotkeys.

PhpStorm launched on xpra display on remote computer. Xpra session attached to x2go-session. My terminal computer connected to remote computer over x2goclient

Comment: Interest: Hotkeys with Ctrl: Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+Tab, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V work perfectly. But, hotkeys Alt+F{n} not worked (ALt+F5, Alt+F7 for toggles panels).

Comment: Issue tracked here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55796

Answer (score 6):

They're probably used by the window manager. Check `Settings > Window Manager > Keyboard`.

Comment: Yes. Problem solved. After change keys in windows manager and Keyboard manager, need relogin for correct work hot keys in my applications.

Comment: Ohh. No. Problem is still. After enter to xfce settings (I dont run window manager settings, i set some changes in session manager) - hot keys stopped worked in my applications. What is devil?

Comment: I was getting weird behaviour when using `Ctrl-Alt-<` in Emacs, removing all the shortcuts fixed that, thanks!

Comment: Helped me with Ubuntu. Windows-moving ALT+F8 and ALT+F7 were getting in the way

Answer (score 2):

in Settings > Settings Manager > Settings Editor > xfce4-keyboad-shortcut , find left_workspace_key and right_workspace_key, remove it (select it and click on reset).